# Ciclo for en python generador de examenes

Tags: python, datetime, generador

Estoy haciendo un generador de calendario de exámenes en python y necesito que mi algoritmo funcione de la siguiente manera:

Yo le doy una fecha y de esa fecha tiene que recorrer 6 días atrás, en caso de haber un sábado o domingo debe correr un día más, hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
from datetime import date,timedelta

fecha_final = date(2019, 1, 15)
fecha_inicial = fecha_final - timedelta(days=6)

i = 1
fecha_nueva = fecha_inicial


for i in range(i < 6):

if fecha_nueva.weekday() == 5:
    print("No hay examen el: " + fecha_nueva)
    fecha_nueva = fecha_inicial + timedelta(days=i)

if fecha_nueva.weekday() == 6:      
    print("No hay examen el: " + fecha_nueva)
    fecha_nueva = fecha_inicial + timedelta(days=i)

else:
    i +=1
print("final")
```

Sin embargo no me logra detectar cuando es sábado o domingo

UPDATE:

Trate de implementarlo de la siguiente forma, sin embargo sigue sin funcionarme :/

```
from datetime import date,timedelta

fecha_final = date(2019, 1, 15)



i = 1

while i < 7:
   fecha_nueva = fecha_final - timedelta(days=1)

   if fecha_nueva.weekday() == 5:
       print("No hay examen el: " + str(fecha_nueva))
   elif fecha_nueva.weekday() == 6:
       print("No hay examen el: " + str(fecha_nueva))
   else:
       i+=1
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es encontrar una fecha tal que, entre esa fecha y la fecha final haya seis días hábiles?

Comment: Por ejemplo, si partimos tal día como hoy, martes 3 de diciembre de 2019 ¿la fecha que buscas como inicio sería el lunes 25 de noviembre? ¿O sería igualmente el miércoles 27 (que es seis días atrás), pero entonces alterarías la fecha final sumándole 2 para pasar a ser el 5 de diciembre?

Comment: Lo dejaré un poco más claro, yo proporciono la fecha de entrega de calificaciones supongamos que es hoy 3 de diciembre, de esa fecha se va 6 días para atrás (o sea 27 de noviembre) como entre esos 6 días hay 2 que no son habiles (sábado y domingo) yo los recupero corriendo la fecha de inicio 2 días más, o sea a 25 de noviembre

Comment: Entonces cada fecha hábil me debería de imprimir un "Este día hay examen" (o algo por el estilo, debido a eso trato de hacerlo con ciclos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tan sólo se tratase de obtener la fecha de inicio a partir de la fecha final, de modo que haya seis días hábiles en medio, sería tan simple como restar 8 días desde la fecha final (ya que siempre encontrarás al menos un fin de semana por el medio), a menos que la fecha final sea lunes, en cuyo caso has de restar 10 días (pues pillarás dos fines de semana por medio).

```
fecha_final = date(2019, 1, 15)
if fecha_final.weekday() == 0: # es lunes
   delta = 10
else:
   delta = 8
fecha_inicio = fecha_final - timedelta(days=delta)
```

Una vez se tiene la fecha de inicio, se recorre en bucle desde esta fecha hasta la final, imprimiendo cada día si hay examen o no:

```
fecha = fecha_inicio
while fecha != fecha_final:
  if fecha.weekday() in [5,6]:
     msg = "No hay examen"
  else:
     msg = "Hay examen"
  print("{}: {}".format(fecha, msg))
  fecha += timedelta(days=1)
```

Saldría en este caso:

```
2019-01-07: Hay examen
2019-01-08: Hay examen
2019-01-09: Hay examen
2019-01-10: Hay examen
2019-01-11: Hay examen
2019-01-12: No hay examen
2019-01-13: No hay examen
2019-01-14: Hay examen
```

Para un caso más genérico en el que pudieras tener otros festivos, o el número de días en vez de 6 sea cualquier otro dado como parámetro, puede ser más sencillo partir de la fecha final e ir decrementando de uno en uno, mirando si el día es hábil y contando cuántos hábiles hay, hasta tener el número de ellos deseado. Cada fecha recorrida se puede ir guardando en una lista con el mensaje apropiado y al final imprimir esa lista al revés. Por ejemplo:

```
def encontrar_fechas_examenes(fecha_final, festivos=None, num_dias=6):
  if festivos is None: festivos = []
  contador = 0
  lista = []
  fecha = fecha_final
  while contador<num_dias:
    if fecha.weekday() in [5, 6]:   # Es fin de semana
      msg = "No hay examen (fin de semana)"
    elif fecha in festivos:
      msg = "No hay examen (festivo)"
    else:
      msg = "Hay examenes"
      contador += 1
    lista.append("{}: {}".format(fecha, msg))
    fecha -= timedelta(days=1)

  return reversed(lista)
```

Que podría llamarse por ejemplo así:

```
festivos = [
            date(2019, 1, 1),
            date(2019, 1, 6)
]
inicio = date(2019, 1, 10)
for fecha in encontrar_fechas_examenes(inicio, festivos, 8):
  print(fecha)
```

y mostraría en este caso:

```
2018-12-31: Hay examenes
2019-01-01: No hay examen (festivo)
2019-01-02: Hay examenes
2019-01-03: Hay examenes
2019-01-04: Hay examenes
2019-01-05: No hay examen (fin de semana)
2019-01-06: No hay examen (fin de semana)
2019-01-07: Hay examenes
2019-01-08: Hay examenes
2019-01-09: Hay examenes
2019-01-10: Hay examenes
```

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba!!!! Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

En este caso sucede que el `for` es innecesario, luego lo suyo es eliminarlo.

Te están pidiendo que verifiques si el día acordado es sábado o domingo para desplazar la fecha del examen... luego el desplazamiento debe ser, necesariamente, de 2 días o de 1:

```
if fecha_nueva.weekday() == 5:
    print("No hay examen el: " + str(fecha_nueva))
    fecha_nueva = fecha_inicial + timedelta(days=1)
    #                                            ^ nos desplazamos 1 dia

if fecha_nueva.weekday() == 6:      
    print("No hay examen el: " + str(fecha_nueva))
    fecha_nueva = fecha_inicial + timedelta(days=1)
    #                                            ^ nos desplazamos 1 dia
```

Aunque también se pueden fusionar ambos condicionales usando un `while`:

```
while fecha_nueva.weekday() == 5 or fecha_nueva.weekday() == 6:
    print("No hay examen el: " + str(fecha_nueva))
    fecha_nueva = fecha_inicial + timedelta(days=1)
```

Nota que también se han modificado las llamadas a `print`. Es necesario convertir `fecha_nueva` a string, con `str()` para que la concatenación se realice correctamente.

Y ya, para rematar, fíjate que ahora la variable `i` no tiene uso alguno, luego también puede ser eliminada.

Comment: Hola Eferion, en el caso de la identación ocurrió un error al pegar mi código, en el visual code sí estaba bien acomodado, mi problema es que yo le doy una fecha (supongamos 19/1/15) y de esa fecha para atrás debe correrse 6 días, si en alguno de esos 6 días hay un sábado o domingo se debe recorrer un día más para poder recuperar esos dos días.

Comment: @ivangarcia82 pues te sugiero que edites la pregunta y dejes el código tal cual aparece en tu editor... en cualquier caso el resto de mi respuesta debería solucionar tu problema

Answer (score 1):

A lo que entiendo, lo que tu buscas creo podría ser de la siguiente manera:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_exam_date(exam_date: date):
    if exam_date.weekday() == 5:
        return exam_date - timedelta(days=6)
    elif exam_date.weekday() == 6:
        return exam_date + timedelta(1)
    else:
        return exam_date

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exam_date = date(2019, 12, 7)
    next_date = get_exam_date(exam_date)

    if exam_date != get_exam_date(exam_date):
        print("No hay examen el: " + str(exam_date))
        print("Nueva fecha: " + str(next_date))
    else:
        print("El examen sera el: " + str(exam_date))
```

Comment: Claro, lo único diferente es que en esos 6 días (hábiles, o sea sin contar sábado y domingo) hay examenes también, esos 6 días sería como el período de examenes